# Download each record in Bigquery as a file to GCS

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Can we download each record in Bigquery to GCS through bq extract or any other means? I tried downloading the entire table reading them individually and creating files but is there an out-of-the-box way that GCP provides? I have 30+ million records in BigQuery and I want to store them as individual records in Bigquery for lookup purposes. We can look at BigQuery but table scan is very costly because some of the record elements are very huge and table scan is close to 10 TB for each scan

Comment: You might want to look at Storage Read API ... see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage   This should allow you to write an app that will read all the records without having to perform a 10TB scan.   There might be an opportunity here for a Dataflow batch pipeline.  I am not aware of any "out of the box" mechanism to translate rows in BigQuery to individual GCS objects.

Comment: Can you clarify your problem and objective? It is not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish or why. For example: Why are you doing table scans? Why do you want to store individual records in Cloud Storage? Dumping a database table is typically done as a single file and not as individual file objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can export data from BigQuery to Google Cloud Storage (GCS) using the  `bq extract` command or through other methods provided by GCP.

To export data from BigQuery to GCS using the bq extract command, you can use the following syntax:

```
bq extract \
--destination_format [FORMAT] \
[PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[TABLE] \
[BUCKET_NAME]/[FILE_NAME_PATTERN]
```

Replace `[FORMAT]` with the desired format for your files (such as CSV, JSON, AVRO, etc.).

This command will export the entire table into GCS in the specified format. However, if you want to store each record individually for lookup purposes, exporting each record as an individual file might not be efficient due to the large number of records.

You can also consider **partitioning** or **segmenting** the data in a meaningful way before exporting. For instance, if there's a particular column or set of columns that can be used for partitioning (like date ranges, categories, etc.), you could partition the data based on those columns to reduce the number of records in each exported file.

Additionally, you might explore other export methods like **Dataflow** or **using client libraries** such as Python's **google-cloud-bigquery library** to create a custom extraction process that suits your specific needs and optimizes the storage for lookup purposes.

Also, according to @Kolban, you might want to try Storage Read API, as it allows you to write an app that will read all the records without having to perform a 10TB scan.

Posting this answer as a Community Wiki for other users to include additional information and if there are other possible workarounds/direct solutions for this use case. Also, for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Please feel free to edit this answer.